# apply function to dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I want to apply my function to dataframe but it shouldn't effect first row. Becouse it is my sum row. When I apply function to dataframe it divide the first row also. I am trying to each value divide by first row value.

How can I succes it? **And also I want to show results with two decimals, like 40,00 not *40,0.**

Here my function and data frame

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[200,200],[40,40],[80,80],[80,80]]), columns= 
  ["Erkek","Kadin"], index=["Base","AB","C1","C2"])


  def yuzde(x):
     x = x/x[0]
     x = x*100
     return round(x,2)

  tablo = df1.apply(yuzde, axis=0)

  print(tablo)
```

my output is :

```
         Erkek  Kadin
   Base  100.0  100.0
   AB     20.0   20.0
   C1     40.0   40.0
   C2     40.0   40.0
```

but I want it like;

```
         Erkek    Kadin
   Base   200     200
   AB     20.00   20.00
   C1     40.00   40.00
   C2     40.00   40.00
```

Thank you,

Comment: format it as a string it will show correctly

Comment: There is some problem in my answer?

Comment: Actually it did big part of my problem bu the point is I need them in float format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest dont use `apply`, because slow, better is use vectorized soluton with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1.iloc[1:] = df1.iloc[1:].div(df1.iloc[0]).mul(100)
print (df1)
      Erkek  Kadin
Base  200.0  200.0
AB     20.0   20.0
C1     40.0   40.0
C2     40.0   40.0
```

If need change format is it possible, but get `string`s add [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df1.iloc[1:] = df1.iloc[1:].div(df1.iloc[0]).mul(100).applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
print (df1)
      Erkek  Kadin
Base    200    200
AB    20.00  20.00
C1    40.00  40.00
C2    40.00  40.00

print (df1.applymap(type))
              Erkek          Kadin
Base  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
AB    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
C1    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
C2    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

---

```
df1.iloc[1:] = df1.iloc[1:].div(df1.iloc[0]).mul(100).applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
df1 = df1.astype(str)
print (df1)
      Erkek  Kadin
Base    200    200
AB    20.00  20.00
C1    40.00  40.00
C2    40.00  40.00

print (df1.applymap(type))
              Erkek          Kadin
Base  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
AB    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
C1    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
C2    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

Comment: @Hüseyin - I think it is not possible if need  double zero `40.0` to `40.00` in floats. What is reason for it? Or need in real data `df1.iloc[1:] = df1.iloc[1:].div(df1.iloc[0]).mul(100).round(2)`?

Comment: Absolutely you are right it is unnecessary but if someone else wants to look tables want to see in that way. I mean it is just for a good view. It is silly but it is also fact. :)